# How to get records if a column has value A, if not then B?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql database. Like

```
+-----+------+------+--------+  
| id  | p_id | lang |  title |
+-----+------+------+--------+  
| 1   |   1  |  en  |  eng1  |
| 2   |   1  |  fr  |  fr1   |
| 3   |   2  |  en  |  eng2  |
+-----+------+------+--------+
```

I want to select records of `P_id` of `lang` = `fr`. If any p_id does not have record in `fr` then select record of `en`.
Like

```
+-----+------+------+--------+  
| id  | p_id | lang |  title |
+-----+------+------+--------+
| 2   |   1  |  fr  |  fr1   |
| 3   |   2  |  en  |  eng2  |
+-----+------+------+--------+
```

Is it possible?

I am Using PHP, MySQL and Joomla.

**Edit :**
1 : There can be more than 2 rows of each p_id with diff lang, like see p_id = 1

```
  +-----+------+------+--------+  
    | id  | p_id | lang |  title |
    +-----+------+------+--------+  
    | 1   |   1  |  en  |  eng1  |
    | 2   |   1  |  fr  |  fr1   |
    | 3   |   2  |  en  |  eng2  |
    | 4   |   1  |  de  |  de1   |
    +-----+------+------+--------+
```

2 : There is surety that each p_id has a raw in lang = en-GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql Query (untested)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.p_id
FROM myTable a
WHERE a.lang = 'fr'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT b.p_id
FROM myTable b
WHERE b.lang = 'en'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1
 FROM myTable c
 WHERE c.lang = 'fr'
 AND c.p_id = b.p_id
)
```

I take all the fr rows then i add all the en where does not exist a fr row.

Comment: This could work (I have not tested), but is there any better way to do this, rather than using nested sub queries?

Comment: mmm yes and no. You need to take all the fr. If a id does not exist for fr then take en. But you need to know which fr you've got... so a nested one will do for now. OtherWise you will have duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
id, p_id, lang, title
FROM
your_table
WHERE lang IN ('fr', 'en')
ORDER BY lang = 'fr' DESC
/*optionally*/
LIMIT 1;
```

The `lang = 'fr'` in the `order by` returns 1 or 0, true or false. This makes sure, that the `fr` record is first.

Or like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
id, p_id, lang, title
FROM
your_table
WHERE lang ='fr'
UNION ALL
SELECT
id, p_id, lang, title
FROM
your_table
WHERE lang ='en'
AND FOUND_ROWS() = 0;
```

This executes the second query in the union only if the first one found no rows.

Comment: Your queries are cont considering records for each p_id.

Comment: They do what? It's not clear to me what the problem is. As far as I can tell, my queries answer your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The following query selects all records with lang = fr:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE lang = 'fr'
```

The following query selects all records with lang = en and no corresponding fr record exists:

```
SELECT en.*
FROM content AS en
LEFT JOIN content AS fr ON en.p_id = fr.p_id AND en.id <> fr.id AND fr.lang = 'fr'
WHERE en.lang = 'en' AND fr.id IS NULL
```

Use `UNION ALL` to combine both results.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5347a/1)

Answer (score 0):

While it works for the dataset you posted, it would require some tweaks.

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9261f/4

It a bit modified answer posted by `fancyPants` above.

```
SELECT id, p_id, lang, title
   FROM `test`
WHERE lang ='fr'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, p_id, lang, title
   FROM `test`
WHERE lang ='en'
AND id > (SELECT id
   FROM `test`
WHERE lang ='fr');
```

From what I understand, the `p_id` with lang=`en` should be after those with lang=`fr`, hence the sub-query.